# Start a Stream/Timer only once

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, timer

I'm trying to set up a timer/stream that checks DateTime and as soon as the day shifts over, it calls a function (_startDayChange()). It all works, but for one problem:
No matter where I start the Timer/Stream from, sooner or later it gets calles a second/third/fourth time and I have multiple timers/streams running all doing the same thing. Here is one code snippet from one of my many attempts:

```
  _timer_stream() {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    var stream = new Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (count) {
      DateTime newTime = DateTime.now();
      int daysSinceLaunch = newTime.difference(dateTime).inDays;
      if (daysSinceLaunch > 0) {
        dateTime = newTime;
        dayHasChanged = true;
        return dayHasChanged;
      } else {
        dayHasChanged = false;
        return dayHasChanged;
      }
    });
    stream.listen((result) {
      if (dayHasChanged == true) {
        _startDayChange();
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm new to programming and banged my head against this for quite a while now. The feeling is I'm missing something fundamental here and need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from?

Comment: I tried: initState() as well as the build method of my the widget that is basically my home screen.

Comment: Why don't you try a simple Timer.periodic with duration 1 day and callback: _startDayChange?

Comment: I want it to trigger at 00:00 am; not after 1 day. And wouldnt that just mean that after a while, I have multiple times running that triger after 1 day? The problem is not with the code not realizing when the day is changing, but with the timer or stream I'm using running multiple times. Good example: When I leave the page and then return, initState and the build method is called again and no matter where I put the code for the timer/stream, a second one is started without the first one ending.

Comment: When you leave the page, you need to cancel the stream subscription in the dispose method. The stream subscription is returned by this line: stream.listen(...). Store the reference and override your widget's dispose method and call .cancel() on the subscription.

Comment: First: Thanks for trying to help! it seems the @dispose() method is not running when I leave the screen (I'm using a button in the bottom bar that pushes a named route); but initState is being called when I return to the page; which is when the second timer/stream starts. How do I triger the dispose when I push another route on top of the stack?

Comment: I tihnk I figured it out! If I use Navigator.pop() before pushing the next route on top; the dispose method gets called and all I can get rid of the stream/timer. Thanks!